# Conditional tag for comments

Tags: comment-meta

How can I check if the current loop is a comment? Something like `is_comment()`.

I'm building a custom `update_x_meta()` function where we update meta data according to the type, example:

```
if ( is_single() || is_attachment() || is_page() ) {
    // post, page, attachment
    update_post_meta($id, $meta_data, $meta_value);
} elseif (is_author()) {
    // author page
    update_user_meta($id, $meta_data, $meta_value);
} elseif ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ) {
    // taxonomies
    update_term_meta($id, $meta_data, $meta_value);
} elseif ( is_comment() ) {
    // comment
    update_comment_meta($id, $meta_data, $meta_value);
}
```

I suppose in order to make this work, I will need to target the conditional tags with a specific ID, like `is_single($id)` etc.  although that may not work given that we can have the same ID for posts, terms...

I feel there should already be an `update_x_meta()` type of function in core already.

Comment: Hm, I haven't seen a comment page yet (other than `is_comments_popup()`). Did you mean to check if you are on a `WP_Comment_Query` loop?

Comment: @JackJohansson Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Although on second thought, the **if statement** in its current form wouldn't work regardless... because `is_single()` will be true even if we are on a `WP_Comment_Query` loop. I'm rethinking this approach. Maybe a `global $post` route...

Comment: I was thinking about the same think for the past 5 minutes. The `WP_Query` doesn't query the comments, so you have to either query the comments manually by `WP_Comment_Query` or check to see if it the post has any comments, and then run the loop. Otherwise, i don't know when `is_comment()` can be true, since comments are manually pulled by `comments_template();` Whenever needed.

Comment: I could do something like `global $wp_query;` and then use conditions like `$wp_query->is_page` etc. The problem is still the same though I guess. Back to the drawing board... =(

Answer (score 1):

The comments popup page contains a loop of the comments, which can be checked by an [`is comments popup()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_comments_popup) conditional, that returns either `true` or `false`. However, i don't see this feature being used in modern development. This might be the only place containing a direct loop of comments.

The `$wp_query` itself does not contain any comment data, except whether the post has any comments or not (and how many of them exist). The comment themselves are called later in the template files (such as `single.php`) by using a loop like this:

```
while ( have_posts() ) { 
    the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'SOME TEMPLATE HERE' ); 
    comments_template();
}
```

The [`comments_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/) itself will use `WP_Comments_Query()` to query a list of comments. So, to be on a comment loop means to be on a page or post template. So the conditional posted in the question won't help, unless we change it like this:

```
if ( is_single() || is_attachment() || is_page() ) {
    // post, page, attachment
    update_post_meta($id, $meta_data, $meta_value);
    if(have_comments()) {
        // Run some stuff here
    }
} elseif (is_author()) {
    // author page
    update_user_meta($id, $meta_data, $meta_value);
} elseif ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ) {
    // taxonomies
    update_term_meta($id, $meta_data, $meta_value);
}
```

Which will update both comments and posts at the same time.

But there is a filter, which will trigger whenever `comment_template()` function is called in the template files, so it might be a place to hook and update the comments meta:

```
add_filter( "comments_template", "update_comments_meta" );
function update_comments_meta($comment_template){
    global $post;
    if ( have_comments() ){
        // Do some stuff here
    }
    return $comment_template;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this Jack +1 -- I am going to see if I can find a more *direct* solution to this. It's a task I have lined up in a few weeks. If nothing profound is found, I will accept this. I like the idea of hooking into `comment_template()`.

Comment: @ChristineCooper You're welcome. I couldn't find anything more direct direct in neither codex nor code reference. However, others might be able to provide an answer if you bump the post to home or leave a message in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop).